# Default GC mode for ASP.NET applications running on IIS 8.5 and Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, garbage-collection, .net-4.5

What is the default GC mode for ASP.NET (NET 4.5) applications running on IIS 8.5 and Windows Server 2012 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the *startupFlags* parameter passed to [CorBindToRuntimeHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231007%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [CorBindToRuntimeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99sz37yh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default:

> STARTUP_CONCURRENT_GC | STARTUP_LOADER_OPTIMIZATION_MULTI_DOMAIN_HOST | STARTUP_LOADER_SAFEMODE | STARTUP_DISABLE_COMMITTHREADSTACK | STARTUP_HOARD_GC_VM

Additionally, *pwszBuildFlavor* is "svr" unless an administrator has modified the registry to specify a different value.

Answer (score 0):

It will be Server mode, unless you've done something unlikely with the config.